# Full calendar - Drag external events into calendar, but event arrays in state does not get updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use Full Calendar in my React project.

When I drag an external event into the calendar, the event array which links to the calendar is not updated although the external event is being visible in the calendar

**Initial state**

```js
calendarEvents: ["Event 1"],
externalEvents: ["Event 2", "Event 3"]
```

After drag an event named Event 2 into the calendar, the externalEvents does not change

**The state should be as follows:**

```js
calendarEvents: ["Event 1", "Event 2"],
externalEvents: ["Event 2", "Event 3"]
```

Here is my sample code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/fullcalendar-react-jp7n1

Thank you for your help.

```js
import React from "react";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import "./styles.css";
import "@fullcalendar/core/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();

  state = {
    calendarWeekends: true,
    calendarEvents: [{ title: "Event 1", start: new Date() }],
    externalEvents: [
      { title: "Event 2", start: new Date() },
      { title: "Event 3", start: new Date() }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-app">
        <div
          id="external-events"
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "50%"
          }}
        >
          <h4>External event</h4>
          {this.state.externalEvents.map(event => {
            return (
              <div
                className="fc-event"
                title={event.title}
                id={event.id}
                key={event.id}
                style={{
                  marginBottom: "2px",
                  marginRight: "10px",
                  padding: "3px",
                  cursor: "pointer"
                }}
              >
                {event.title}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "50%"
          }}
        >
          <h4>Events from state</h4>
          {this.state.calendarEvents.map(event => {
            return (
              <div
                style={{
                  marginBottom: "2px",
                  marginRight: "10px",
                  padding: "3px",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  backgroundColor: "green"
                }}
              >
                {event.title}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div className="demo-app-calendar">
          <FullCalendar
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            header={{
              left: "prev,next today",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek"
            }}
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
            weekends={this.state.calendarWeekends}
            events={this.state.calendarEvents}
            dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let draggableEl = document.getElementById("external-events");
    new Draggable(draggableEl, {
      itemSelector: ".fc-event",
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        let title = eventEl.getAttribute("title");
        let id = eventEl.getAttribute("id");
        return {
          title: title,
          id: id
        };
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is expected. fullcalendar does not update the list of events you originally gave it, just because you dragged an event on the calendar. When you give it the events via the "events" option, that's a one-way process, going into fullCalendar. It's just an object you pass in, it does not maintain a reference to it. If you want to add the new dragged-in event to your list, you'll need to write your own code to update it directly.

Comment: Thank @ADyson for your comment